# FTP file with new name that have prefix of format yyyymmdd_hhmmss

Tags: cmd, ftp

I wrote below command:
ftp

```
open server.com
username
password

cd destination_path\

put \\source_path\test.txt

rename test.txt test_success_%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~_2%.%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt

quit
```

Rename is successful but with name `test_success_%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~_2%.%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt`

not like `test_success_20170126_022545.txt` (Which i want).

Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it with this:

```
rename test.txt 
test_success_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
```

My result was: test_success_20170126_100649.txt
Notice: Write it in one line, I cut it here in two lines for a better view.

Comment: I am not sure..My result is 

test_success_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt             only.
Correct result will come in cmd not when ftp connection is open...

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the ftp interpreter is not processing the %'s. I usually write the ftp commands to a file, then run it.

```
SET "FTPFILE=%TEMP%\myscript.tmp"

ECHO>"%FTPFILE%" open server.com
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" username
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" password
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" cd destination_path\
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" put \\source_path\test.txt
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" rename test.txt test_success_%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~_2%.%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt
ECHO>>"%FTPFILE%" quit

ftp -n -s:"%FTPFILE%"
```

Comment: Above code is working fine in cmd..unfortunately my job allows command in ftp.exe
So above code will not fit for my application.
Is there any other way to do..

Answer (score 0):

The code you show appears to be an `ftp` session, but not a `cmd` session. The `%` variable expansion is specific to `cmd` but not to `ftp`, therefore your code cannot work.

I would use a fixed temporary file name in the `ftp` session and do the renaming later in a `cmd` session:

**`ftp` session:**

```
open server.com
username
password

cd destination_path\

put \\source_path\test.txt

quit
```

**`cmd` session:**

```
rename "destination_path\test.txt" "test_success_%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~-2%.%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt"
```

By the way, there is a typo: you stated `%date:~_2%` rather than `%date:~-2%`...

Comment: After quit, my application closes. there will be no cmd session after that.

Comment: You could open a `cmd` then. How do you run `ftp`?

Comment: our ssis package execute ftp.exe and the  command will take from config file. So we can use the same package with just new command in config file. So just we want to do with same package with added commands.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with SSIS. Anyway, you need something that is capable of understanding and expanding variables like `%date%`, like `cmd`; otherwise you cannot solve that. Perhaps instead of callingt `ftp`, you could call a batch file (a script executed by `cmd`) that contains the call of `ftp`, followed by the `rename` command line I mentioned above...